# Building and updating large views

Tags: iphone, xcode, cgcontext

Looking at many existing apps, I have noticed a recurring theme where a (scrolling) view is really made up of many squares, like 100 by 100 of them. Wanting to do something similar, the question come to mind as to whether this view is created by hundreds of subviews, or one view that gets updated section as needed via a setNeedDisplay.

on the one hand using hundreds of subviews seems really memory and processing taxing. But on the other hand, how and should one retain the drawing context, that ultimately only seems available in the drawRect method however its called.

Comment: I am not quite sure, but I think what you are referring to is actually `CATiledLayer` not `subview`s per se. Can you provide a link, code or something. It helps. (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

What is giving you the idea that a scrolling view is made up of say 100x100 squares? If you think this is the case because you are seeing squares load up as you scroll, the reason is probably because the application is using a moderately advanced technique called tiling.

There is reference material from Apple on [CATiledLayer here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) and an [example of usage by Bill Dudney here](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/catiledlayer_example).

Comment: Perhaps I should have stated a view I want to make scrollable, and the best way to build the map, For example SimCity or Civilization, you have the large map and then your viewing a portion of it. The map being made up of a grid of (isometric) squares for example. I didn't know about the CATiledLayer, I'll take a look at it.